# Magento. Create attribute for grouped products only

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I am trying to create attribute programmatically for all grouped products on my site. I am trying to create custom attribute set with group.

```
$oEntitySetup = $this;
$oEntitySetup->removeAttribute('catalog_product', 'grouped_base_price');

$skeletonID=$oEntitySetup->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product','Default');
$entityTypeId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getResource()
    ->getEntityType()
    ->getId(); //product entity type

$attributeSet = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')
    ->setEntityTypeId($entityTypeId)
    ->setAttributeSetName("oggy_attr_set");

$attributeSet->validate();
$attributeSet->save();

$attributeSet->initFromSkeleton($skeletonID)->save();

$data = array(
    'attribute_set' => 'oggy_attr_set',
    'group'    => 'General',
    'label'    => 'Base Price',
    'apply_to' => 'grouped',
    'input'    => 'text',
    'visible'  => true,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'required' => true,
    'position' => 1,
    'global'   => 'Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL',
    'note'     => "Default Price For Configurable Products"
);
$oEntitySetup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'grouped_base_price', $data);

$oEntitySetup->endSetup();
```

The problem is that attribute appears in all product types. But i need for grouped products only. What i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign created attribute to a particular "attribute set" and then while creating any group product - select this attribute set.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I have updated my question, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

in your code $oEntitySetup have all products, you never take a specific group, and is sure you gift the new attribute to all products